# Can I save a Time object in a model attribute of class Date_time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm having some trouble getting a model to save a date_time attribute.

The attribute is of class DateTime, whereas the class of the object I am trying to save is Time.

Is it possible to save a Time object in a DateTime attribute?

This is how it looks in Schema.rb:

```
 create_table "tables", :force => true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.datetime "time_spot"
  end
```

Comment: Please show us how you defined this attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually have to do any manipulation to save a Time object in a DateTime field. ActiveRecord will store the Time object in the proper SQL format. For example:

```
t = Tables.create :time_spot => Time.now
t.time_spot
=> Wed, 16 Feb 2011 07:46:59 UTC +00:00
```